# clang++ error message when using C++0x: call to deleted constructor of

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Hello I have upgraded my Xcode to version 4.2 and clang++ to version:

```
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

When try to compile the following code with clang -std=c++0x

```
#include <memory>
#include <limits>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>


class ilpConstraintImpl {
public:
    virtual ~ilpConstraintImpl() {}
};


class ilpConstraint {
public:
    ilpConstraint(ilpConstraintImpl* implptr):impl(implptr) { }
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<ilpConstraintImpl> impl;
};

class ilpExprImpl {
public:
    virtual ilpConstraint operator<= (const double rs)=0;
    virtual ~ilpExprImpl() {}
};



class ilpExpr {
 public:
    virtual ~ilpExpr() {};
    ilpConstraint operator<= (const double rs) { return impl->operator<=(rs); }
    ilpExpr(ilpExprImpl* implptr):impl(implptr) { }
    boost::shared_ptr<ilpExprImpl> impl;
};
```

I get the following error:

```
./test.h:46:54: error: call to deleted constructor of 'ilpConstraint'
    ilpConstraint operator<= (const double rs) { return impl->operator<=(rs); }
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./test.h:28:7: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
class ilpConstraint {
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiling without -std=c++0x works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a clang bug to me.  I'm working with a later clang version which does not have this behavior.  You might try giving `ilpConstraint` an explicit copy constructor as a temporary workaround.

Comment: That kind of works .... adding a copy constructor like:  ilpConstraint(const ilpConstraint & impcon):impl(impcon.impl) { }
 moves the problem to to shared_ptr with the same error message :)

Comment: Sorry.  You could try the `std::shared_ptr` from libc++.  You have to select libc++ under the "C++ Standard Library" settings (it is not the default).

Comment: I seem to remember that there was a problem with boost shared_ptr having a deleted copy constructor, relying on a constructor template for doing the copy and being favored. Later boost versions fixed that problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that older shared_ptr versions declare move constructors, which will make clang implicitly declare and delete its copy constructors (like C++11 requires). Earlier C++11 drafts didn't implicitly declare copy constructors at all in such a case (so would use the template). This shared_ptr change may perhaps affect things. Maybe clang doesn't implicitly declare a move ctor for ilpConstraint for whatever reason, meaning that it will only provide a deleted copy constructor for ilpConstraint (since it can't call the shared_ptr's copy constructor).

Answer (score 3):

With C++0x support the boost smart pointers define move constructors. This however disables implicit copying by the automatically generated copy constructor and assignment operator.

There is a patch for boost's smart pointers which refits the copy constructors and the assignment operators if the support for C++0x is detected.
It can be found here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/73202

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, when one of the members of my class, didn't have a default constructor anymore.

```
struct OrderContact {
    std::string name;
    std::string phone;
    OrderContact() {}  // error without this constructor
    OrderContact(std::string contactName, std::string contactPhone) : name(contactName), phone(contactPhone) {
    }
};

class Order {
public:
    OrderContact contact;
}
```

Comment: +1, I ran into this same error message today and this was the cause of mine.

Comment: Same, ran into this problem and was fixed with a default ctor